# expr non-numeric argument shell script

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

The below check is not working:

```
if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ])
```

and returns `expr non-numeric argument shell script`.

Always it is going to else. Please tell me what is the mistake.

Earlier I was not using while so the same thing was working fine now suddenly when I did put it in the while loop it is no working.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
echo "`${BOLD}`    ***** Checking Memory Utilization User*****`${UNBOLD}`"
echo "==================================================="

IFS='|'
cat configMachineDetails.txt | grep -v "^#" | while read MachineType UserName MachineName
do
    export MEMORY_USAGE1=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} prstat -t -s rss 1 2 | tr '%' ' '| awk '$5>5.0'`
    export LEN=`echo "$MEMORY_USAGE1"|wc -l`
    export CNPROC=`echo "$MEMORY_USAGE1"|grep "NPROC"|wc -l`
    export CTotal=`echo "$MEMORY_USAGE1"|grep "Total"|wc -l`

    if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ]
    then
        echo "`${BOLD}`**************All usages are normal !!!!!! *************`${UNBOLD}`"
    else
        echo "`${BOLD}`**** Memory(%) is more than 5% in MachineType $MachineType  UserName $UserName
 MachineName  $MachineName   *******`${UNBOLD}`"
        echo "===================================================="
        echo "$MEMORY_USAGE1"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: `grep -v "^#" configMachineDetails.txt | while ...`. Also, it's not likely that you need to export any of those variables.

Comment: I like to change the interpret decl to add the `-x` and/or `-v` options: `#!/usr/bin/ksh -xv`.  This prints a lot of stuff, but it helps me trace through the substitutions the shell is making.  Try it and update your question with just the output lines around the line in question.

Comment: Also, note that while ksh will work with pipes into `while` and leave variables with their new values aftwerwards, other shells such as Bash create a subshell and the new values are lost. In Bash, `a=1; echo "hi" | while read b; do echo $b; a=2; done; echo $a` prints "hi" and "1". This will produce the expected "2": `a=1; while read b; do echo $b; a=2; done < <(echo "hi"); echo $a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following statements before your `if` statement:

```
echo "[$MEMORY_USAGE1]"
echo "[$LEN]"
echo "[$CNPROC]"
echo "[$CTotal]"
```

and see what comes out. That error is alnmost invariably caused, surprisingly enough :-), by passing non-numeric data to `expr` and the `echo` statements should tell you exactly what the problem is.

For example:

```
pax> expr 1 + x
expr: non-numeric argument
```

---

Based on your comment that your output is:

```
[ NPROC USERNAME SWAP RSS MEMORY TIME CPU
Total: 143 processes, 2449 lwps, load averages: 1.76, 2.56, 2.94 
NPROC USERNAME SWAP RSS MEMORY TIME CPU
Total: 148 processes, 2443 lwps, load averages: 1.82, 2.57, 2.95]
[ 4]
[ 2]
[ 2]
```

it's possible that the spaces preceding your numeric values are causing your problems. Try replacing all your occurrences of:

```
|wc -l
```

with:

```
|wc -l|sed 's/ //g'
```

to get rid of spaces in the `wc` output.

Comment: With if I should use 
if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ] 
or 
if [ $LEN -eq `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ] 

The value is 
[ NPROC USERNAME  SWAP   RSS MEMORY      TIME  CPU
Total: 143 processes, 2449 lwps, load averages: 1.76, 2.56, 2.94
 NPROC USERNAME  SWAP   RSS MEMORY      TIME  CPU
Total: 148 processes, 2443 lwps, load averages: 1.82, 2.57, 2.95]
[       4]
[       2]
[       2]

the values are given in asked order.

Comment: @Kimi: It's the spaces in the values that are causing the problem: `expr " 2" + " 2"` -> "expr: non-numeric argument", `expr "2" + "2"` -> "4"

Comment: It shouldn't matter in this case - I tested both and they worked fine on numerics. Technically `-eq` is numeric and `=` is string. But I noticed you have spaces in the variables so you might want to try putting `|sed 's/ //g'` after all the `wc -l` bits (to remove spaces from the `wc` output).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ksh's (also works in Bash) builtin arithmetic operations and comparisons?

Instead of:

```
if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ]
```

Try:

```
if (( LEN == CNPROC + CTotal ))
```

It's much more forgiving of spaces in the values.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC + $CTotal` ]
```

with

```
if [ $LEN = `expr $CNPROC+$CTotal` ]
```

(no space between operand) see if that helps

Comment: This does not work. `ksh -c 'CNPROC=1 && CTotal=1 && result=$(expr $CNPROC+$CTotal); echo "${result}"'` outputs `1+1` which is not numeric and is unlikely to be the same string as `$LEN`